# Valgrind is giving an invalid free error message

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, free

I have a hash table that is an array of bucket pointers (nodes are just called buckets in this project). The hash table uses linked list chaining to avoid collisions. Here are my data structures:

```
typedef struct bucket {
   char *key;
   void *value;
   struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;

typedef struct {
   int key_count;
   int table_size;
   void (*free_value)(void *);
   Bucket **buckets;
} Table;
```

Valgrind is giving me an invalid free() error message at line: `table->free_value(curr->value);` 
In the method:

```
/* Removes a bucket consisting of a key and value pair */
int remove_entry(Table * table, const char *key) {
  unsigned int hc = 0;
  int found = 0;
  Bucket *curr;
  Bucket *prev;
  if (table == NULL || key == NULL) {
    return FAIL;
  }
  hc = hash_code(key)%(table->table_size);
  if (table->buckets[hc] != NULL) {
    curr = table->buckets[hc];
    prev = NULL;
    while (curr != NULL) {
      if (strcmp(curr->key, key) == 0) {
        found = 1;
        if (table->free_value != NULL && curr->value != NULL) {
          table->free_value(curr->value); 
          if (curr == table->buckets[hc]) {
            table->buckets[hc] = curr->next;
            free(curr->key);
            free(curr);
            curr = NULL;
            (table->key_count)--;
            return SUCC;
          }
          prev->next = curr->next;
          free(curr->key);
          free(curr);
          curr = NULL;
          (table->key_count)--;
          return SUCC;
        } else {
          if (curr == table->buckets[hc]) {
            table->buckets[hc] = curr->next;
            free(curr->key);
            free(curr);
            curr = NULL;
            (table->key_count)--;
            return SUCC;
          }
          prev->next = curr->next;
          free(curr->key);
          free(curr);
          curr = NULL;
          (table->key_count)--;
          return SUCC;
        }
      }
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
    }
  }
  if (found == 0) {
    return FAIL;
  }
  return SUCC;
}
```

I am not sure why it is saying that. Here is my put() method:

```
/* Puts a key value pair in. If the key exists, the value is updated, otherwise  the pair is added. */
int put(Table *table, const char *key, void *value) {
  unsigned int hc = 0;
  Bucket *curr;
  Bucket *new_bucket;
  char *copy_key;

  if (table == NULL || key == NULL) {
    return FAIL;
  }

  copy_key = malloc(sizeof(strlen(key) + 1));
  if (copy_key == NULL) {
    return FAIL;
  }
  strcpy(copy_key, key);

  hc = hash_code(key)%(table->table_size);
  if (table->buckets[hc] != NULL) {
    curr = table->buckets[hc];
    while (curr != NULL) {
      if (strcmp(curr->key, key) == 0) {
        if (curr->value != NULL && value != NULL) {
          table->free_value(curr->value); /* Getting the invalid free error here again */
         }
         curr->value = value;
         free(copy_key);
         return SUCC;
      }
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr = table->buckets[hc];
    new_bucket = malloc(sizeof(*new_bucket));
    if (new_bucket == NULL) {
      free(copy_key);
      return FAIL;
    }
    new_bucket->value = value;
    new_bucket->key = copy_key;
    new_bucket->next = curr;
    table->buckets[hc] = new_bucket;
    (table->key_count)++;
    return SUCC;
  } else if (table->buckets[hc] == NULL) {
    new_bucket = malloc(sizeof(*new_bucket));
    if (new_bucket == NULL) {
      free(copy_key);
      return FAIL;
    }
    new_bucket->value = value;
    new_bucket->key = copy_key;
    table->buckets[hc] = new_bucket;
    table->buckets[hc]->next = NULL;
    (table->key_count)++;
    return SUCC;
  }
  free(copy_key);
  return FAIL;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you've given us the complete valgrind error.  Invalid Free comes in several varieties (free a pointer that was never allocated; double-free; header/trailer is corrupt, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and I thought, "you are making this way too hard". I'm not trying to be a smart ass but consider the code below which performs the same function with a lot less code. One goal in C code is to minimize duplicate blocks of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SUCC 0
#define FAIL 1

typedef struct bucket {
    char *key;
    void *value;
    struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;

typedef struct {
    int key_count;
    int table_size;
    void (*free_value)(void *);
    Bucket **buckets;
} Table;

unsigned int hash_code(const char *key) { // dummy stupid hash function
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    while(*key) {
        hash += *key++;
    }
    return hash;
}

/* Puts a key value pair in. If the key exists, the value is updated, otherwise  the pair is added. */
int put(Table *table, const char *key, void *value) {

    if(table == 0 || key == 0) {
        return FAIL;
    }

    unsigned int hc = hash_code(key)%(table->table_size);
    Bucket **prev = &table->buckets[hc];
    Bucket *curr  = *prev;
    while(curr && strcmp(curr->key, key)) {
        prev = &curr->next;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if(curr) {
        if(table->free_value && curr->value) {
            table->free_value(curr->value);
        }
        curr->value = value;
    } else {
        Bucket *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        if(p == 0) {
            return FAIL;
        }
        if((p->key = strdup(key)) == 0) {
            free(p);
            return FAIL;
        }
        *prev = p;
        p->next = 0;
        p->value = value;
        table->key_count++;
    }
    return SUCC;
}

/* Removes a bucket consisting of a key and value pair */
int remove_entry(Table * table, const char *key) {

    if (table == NULL || key == NULL) {
        return FAIL;
    }

    unsigned int hc = hash_code(key)%(table->table_size);
    Bucket **prev = &table->buckets[hc];
    Bucket *curr  = *prev;
    while(curr && strcmp(curr->key, key)) {
        prev = &curr->next;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if(curr == 0) {
        return FAIL;
    }

    if(table->free_value && curr->value) {
        table->free_value(curr->value); 
    }
    *prev = curr->next;
    free(curr->key);
    free(curr);
    table->key_count--;
    return SUCC;
}

void print_table(Table *table, FILE *file) {
    printf("table key_count=%d {\n", table->key_count);
    for(int i = 0; i != table->table_size; i++) {
        if(table->buckets[i]) {
            printf("[%d]", i);
            for(Bucket *b = table->buckets[i]; b; b = b->next) {
                printf(" %s", b->key);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Bucket *buckets[100] = { 0 };
    Table table;
    table.table_size = 100;
    table.key_count = 0;
    table.free_value = 0;
    table.buckets = buckets;

    int ch;
    while((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "p:r:x")) != -1) {
        switch(ch) {
            case 'p':
                printf("put %s\n", optarg);
                put(&table, optarg, optarg);
                break;
            case 'r':
                printf("remove %s\n", optarg);
                remove_entry(&table, optarg);
                break;
            case 'x':
                print_table(&table, stdout);
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("done\n");
    print_table(&table, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The only "clever" part is what is happening with `Bucket **prev`. That takes a little study. The rest should be straight forward.

And here's a little shell script to run some test cases:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set valgrind = valgrind
set valgrind = ""

cc -Wall hash.c -o hash
$valgrind ./hash -pa ; # add "a"
$valgrind ./hash -pa -ra ; # add "a" rm "a"
$valgrind ./hash -pab -pba  ; # same bucket
$valgrind ./hash -pab -pba -rab ; # same bucket
$valgrind ./hash -pab -pba -rba  ; # same bucket
$valgrind ./hash -pab -pab  ; # add "ab" twice
$valgrind ./hash -pba -pab -pab -pab  ;
```

Maybe I'll get some flack for doing your homework, I don't know. In any event, one could learn something from the code and seeing how it makes the problem much smaller.